# i got this error "cannot find flag:2 invalidate any flag:{6}" , trying to parse data from edittext using "afterTextCahnged" and editable in data class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

how do i solve this error?
// setter function in data class

```
fun setSize(editable: Editable) {
    editable.toString().toDoubleOrNull()?.let { size = it }
}
```

in xml

```
 <EditText
  android:afterTextChanged="@{Text -> shoeListingsViewModel.shoe.setSize(Text)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing parantheses in the text parameter.

```
  android:afterTextChanged="@{(text) -> shoeListingsViewModel.shoe.setSize(text)}" />
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question , but still didn't work